# How to test a monorepo locally?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I got a big project that is a monorepo consisting of multiple scripts and libraries, its structure is the following:

```
package.json // "private":true
 \packages
    \comp1
       \package.json // an actual component
    \comp2
       \package.json // an actual component
    \comp3
       \package.json // an actual component
```

I've made a `monorepo.tgz` using `yarn pack`.

Then I made a test app whose `package.json` look like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    // this is a script in one of the monorepo's components
    "start": "ui-build --bundle --watch -p 3000"
  }
  "dependencies": {
    "comp1": "../monorepo/monorepo.tgz",
    "comp2": "../monorepo/monorepo.tgz",
    "comp3": "../monorepo/monorepo.tgz",
  ...
```

but its not working, when I run `start` its complaining  that `ui-build: command not found`.
How can I test this monorepo locally to simulate a published npm package as closely as possible?

Comment: did you try npm / yarn install?

Comment: @pythan yes, it executes fine, and I see the error I mentioned when I run `yarn start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `npm link` (or `yarn link`), you can 'install' the packages from your local development environment.

To do this, you first run `npm link` in the directory of the package you want to install, so in `\packages\comp1`. Then in your testapp, run `npm link comp1`. This will install your package. Repeat for any others you want to install.

More info:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found that https://verdaccio.org/ is the best tool to test a library without deploying to an npm repository

Answer (score 0):

To import a file directly without using `npm link` or `yarn link` you have to prepend the path with `file:`. And I believe you would have to pack each file, but you can link directly to the path without packing it as well. Make sure to build it if you are linking directly to the local package folder.

For your example:

```
"comp1": "file:../monorepo/comp1.tgz",
"comp2": "file:../monorepo/comp2.tgz",
"comp3": "file:../monorepo/comp3.tgz",
```

or

```
"comp1": "file:../path/to/monorepo/packages/comp1",
"comp2": "file:../path/to/monorepo/packages/comp2",
"comp3": "file:../path/to/monorepo/packages/comp3",
```